# iPad SplitView cannot resize its PrimaryView width correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit, storyboard

Hi guys I encountered a weird problem with the horizontal size of the `PrimaryView` of `SplitView`. It seems that `SplitView` cannot auto resize its `PrimaryView` width properly during view initialization, and thus the `TableView` relies on it also has a wrong width.

Here is the screenshot of the simulator (iOS 14 - 16 all have this problem) and you could see the `TableCell` has a left part that is outside of the screen:

[image]

This is my `MasterViewController`:

```swift
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        setUpTableViewContraints()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // Content configuration.
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = "Cell Item \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        
        // Style and layout configuration.
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return cell
    }
    
    private func setUpTableViewContraints() {
        let constraints = [
            tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
            tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

This is my `DetailViewController` (nothing inside):

```swift
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I have tried modifying almost all the properties inside `storyboard`, setting up `LayoutAnchors` or `frame` during runtime, but nothing can solve the problem. The `TableCell` is always having incorrect width like the screenshot above.

I am expecting the `PrimaryView` of the `SplitView` has a correct width. I haven't seen anyone posting something similar in the forum so I am guessing I might have made a very funny mistake. But I just could not figure out where it is...

Comment: The picture you show looks correct to me. But it's not clear what you expect. And everything depends on how the split view is setup but you don't show anything about how you setup the split view. Please update your question and clarify exactly how you want the primary view to appear. What width exactly do you consider the correct width? A split view has many options. Tell us what all of the desired behaviors that you want.

Comment: Also, why are you messing the constraints of the table view in a UITableViewController? Remove that code. There's no reason to be doing any of that.